# Can someone suggest/ point me towards various Sakhas of Asvalayana Grihya sutras, Rigveda?

Tags: rig-veda, grihya-sutra

I have been trying to find information about various sakhas of Asvalayana Sutra to which I belong but can't find any online.

Also can a Srauta be a smarta?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  The Ashvalayana Grihya Sutras associated with the (now-lost) Ashvalayana Shaka of the Rig Veda.  As far as I know, the Ashvalayana Grihya Sutras does not itself have multiple Shakhas associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Presently,  shakala branch is most prevalent and other less prevalent is bashkala (बाष्कलशाखा).

Shrauta is the highest form of vedic living according to the prescribed rituals.

Those who cannot maintain shrauta agni usually have smarta agni.

Another meaning of smarta is of a specific community of brahmins. They too can take up Shrauta upasana if willing.